# Solr number range facet count wrong

Tags: solr, numbers, range, facet

I try to count issue 1 to 5 with this range facet query:

```
...&facet.range=issue&facet.range.start=1&q=magid:abc&facet.range.end=5&facet.range.gap=1
```

It returns:

```
<lst name="issue">
      <lst name="counts">
        <int name="1">5</int>
        <int name="2">7</int>
        <int name="3">9</int>
        <int name="4">7</int>
      </lst>
```

There's no issue 5 @@??? Also issue 1 should be 3, 5 is for issue 2 (Then I think "Hey! IT CAN'T BE array element starts from 0" problem, right?!..."). I chnage facet.range.start to 0 and do query again. This time it returns:

```
<lst name="issue">
      <lst name="counts">
        <int name="0">3</int>
        <int name="1">5</int>
        <int name="2">7</int>
        <int name="3">9</int>
        <int name="4">7</int>
      </lst>
```

Oh My! it should be issue 1~5, instead 0~4? Why are Solr doing this? It is really confusing me!

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that these are not 0-based index values. The values you see are the actual values being indexed as tokens, so if you index values from 1 to 5 you should see values from 1 to 5

So, if you want to make sure if you have documents with value 5 or not, the best way to debyg this from the Schema Browser -> Term info

So, go to Solr Admin interface, select the core, click on schema browser, choose the field name you want to see term info for, then click on Load term info.

Comment: Nah! I'm sure I have issue value 5 since I query with 'magid:abc AND issue:5' in admin and it returns significant result. On the other hand, use 'magid:abc AND issue:0' returns none, so it doesn't make sense that name='0' is counted 3.